# Javascript grouping

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm receiving data from an Angular service as follow:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "country": "Germany",
      "iso": "de",
      "city": "Berlin",
      "zone": "2",
    },
    {
      "country": "Germany",
      "iso": "de",
      "city": "Frankfurt",
      "zone": "5",
    },
    {
      "country": "USA",
      "iso": "us",
      "city": "Chicago",
      "zone": "18",
    },
    {
      "country": "USA",
      "iso": "us",
      "city": "New York",
      "zone": "16",
    },
    {
      "country": "USA",
      "iso": "us",
      "city": "San Francisco",
      "zone": "54",
    }
}
```

I would like to transform these data so I can use the [AutoComplete PrimeNG widget](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/autocomplete) which require the following data format as input:

```json
groupedByCountry =   [
      {
        label: 'Germany', value: 'de',
        items: [
          {label: 'Berlin', value: '2'},
          {label: 'Frankfurt', value: '5'}
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'USA', value: 'us',
        items: [
          {label: 'Chicago', value: '18'},
          {label: 'New York', value: '16'},
          {label: 'San Francisco', value: '54'}
        ]
      }
 ];
```

I'm not doing JavaScript on a daily basis and haven't be able to do this transformation so far. If someone could assist it would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```js
let input = JSON.parse(`[
    {
      "country": "Germany",
      "iso": "de",
      "city": "Berlin",
      "zone": "2"
    },
    {
      "country": "Germany",
      "iso": "de",
      "city": "Frankfurt",
      "zone": "5"
    },
    {
      "country": "USA",
      "iso": "us",
      "city": "Chicago",
      "zone": "18"
    },
    {
      "country": "USA",
      "iso": "us",
      "city": "New York",
      "zone": "16"
    },
    {
      "country": "USA",
      "iso": "us",
      "city": "San Francisco",
      "zone": "54"
    }
  ]`)
const res = Object.values(input.reduce((acc, el)=>{
  if(!acc[el.country]){
    acc[el.country] = {
      label: el.country,
      value: el.iso,
      items: [
        {
          label: el.city, 
          value: el.zone
        }
      ]
    }
  } else {
    acc[el.country].items.push({
      label: el.city, 
      value: el.zone
    })
  }
  return acc;
}, {}))
console.log(res)
```

in few words:

1. create a Map like `country -> object`
2. for each element of the array, if in the map that country already exists, then just push the new element, otherwise create it